# How do I add a field for a header for an authentication token for Swagger UI?

Tags: rest, service, documentation, swagger-ui

My team has just started creating RESTful services for data that has previously been handled by a large monolithic legacy application.  We want to document the api with Swagger UI and I have set up with one problem.

I need to pass a SAML token as a header parameter, otherwise when we try to click on the "Try it out!" button I get a 401 Authentication error.  How do I add a field to the Swagger UI so that someone can put a String for a SAML token to be sent in the request?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually really easy.  I saw references to the answer in the documentation but I didn't really understand what it was saying.  There is a field at the top next to where your service URL goes and you can use that field to input a string to pass as a header value.   That input field has an id of #input_apiKey.

Then in the index.html file you just add a line to the addApiKeyAuthorization() javascript function telling it to take the value of that field and pass it as whatever value you need.

Example:

```
  function addApiKeyAuthorization(){
    var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
    if(key && key.trim() != "") {
         swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("samlToken", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("samlToken", key, "header"));
         swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("Content-Type", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Content-Type", "application/json", "header"));
         swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("Accept", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Accept", "application/json", "header"));
    }
  }

  $('#input_apiKey').change(addApiKeyAuthorization);
```

This sets the Content-Type and Accept headers to the same values for every request, and takes the value in that input field at the top of the page in the green header and sets it as my SAML token.  So now if I paste in a valid SAML string my request works and I get data back!

Comment: How does the yaml/json spec look like?